# Prolog: a(b,c) and a(X,Y):-a(Y,X), query a(c,b) returns infinite true?

Tags: prolog

Here is my knowledge base:

```
a(b,c). 
a(X,Y):-a(Y,X).
```

Here is my query: `a(c,b).`

I am using SWI-Prolog. I thought that this query would lead to the program printing "true". However, instead it prints "true" and continues to print true if I hit the semicolon... until FOREVER.

Why doesn't it stop?

My thoughts: First, X is bound to b and Y is bound to c. Then, Prolog tests a(b,c) and finds that this is true. Therefore, a(c,b) is true as well and SWI-Prolog should print true once. However, since it prints true forever as long as I keep hitting that semicolon, this leads me to think that something recursive is going on. Where is this happening? Help!

EDIT: More specifically my question is why does the program pause after each "true" and wait for me to press the semicolon or another key instead of just being done? If I have two predicates human(socrates) and mortal(X):-humans(X), the response to the query mortal(socrates) will be a single "true". (Sorry if I failed to make this clear above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog first proves `a(c,b)` by means of the second rule followed by the first. Then, it proves `a(c,b)` by means of three invocations of the second rule followed by the first. Then, by five invocations of the second rule, etc. Prolog's inference algorithm is a depth-first search without a closed set, i.e. it doesn't keep track of what it has already proved and happily proves it again.

If you don't want this behavior, you should either rewrite the rules as, e.g.,

```
a_fact(b, c).
a(X, Y) :- a_fact(X, Y).
a(Y, X) :- a_fact(X, Y).
```

... or use some kind of [tabling execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Tabling). I don't think SWI-Prolog supports tabling, though.

Comment: ...Or just use `a(b,c) :- !.` to get the desired result.

Comment: @duri: that fails when there's more than one base case.

Comment: Wait - it first proves a(c,b), then proves a(c,b) again? Why doesn't it stop after proving a(c,b) the first time?

Comment: @NullPointer: because that would require a more expensive (in terms of memory) inference algorithm. The burden of preventing infinite loops is on the programmer, not the language.

Comment: I don't understand why prolog needs to prove it again. Once it proves it once, it prints true. The goal (proving it true or false) has been reached. Why does it need to prove it again?

Comment: @NullPointer: because you ask it to by pressing `;`.

Comment: Oh. Could you please try to explain what the inference algorithm is doing here in more detail? I want to know why this creates an infinite loop while something like mortal(socrates) when human(socrates) and mortal(X):-humans(X) does not (why does the program wait for me to hit a semicolon instead of just being done)

Comment: @duri: Consider `a(b,b)`. It should fail, but with a cut as you suggest it would loop again.

Comment: @NullPointer: when proving `a(b,c)` the first time, Prolog notices there is one more clause for `a/2` that might match `a(b,c)` so it makes a **choice point**. Then, when you ask for the next solution, it enters that clause, substituting `X=b, Y=c` and enters the recursive call. Try issuing `trace. a(b,c).` at the Prolog prompt (check the SWI manual for how `trace` works).

Comment: Ah, I see what is happening now. Thanks!